# Replace/Add string in textarea in js

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a textarea and some buttons. Onclick of each button I have to do following:

1. Check if textarea contains some text XXX.
2. If contains then remove it.
3. If not then add it.

How can I do this in javascript? I have tried following but it does not work:

```
function addRecip(con){
    var myvalue = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;
    if(myvalue.indexof(con+",")==-1){
        document.getElementById("textarea1").value = myvalue + con + ",";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("textarea1").value = myvalue.replace(con + ",","");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on button.It fails on line `if(myvalue.indexof(con+",")==-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexof` is actually meant to be spelled `indexOf`, and JavaScript is case-sensitive.

This works:

```
function addRecip(con){
    var myvalue = document.getElementById("textarea1").value;
    if(myvalue.indexOf(con+",")==-1){
        document.getElementById("textarea1").value = myvalue + con + ",";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("textarea1").value = myvalue.replace(con + ",","");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great to hear! If you feel that this answer is appropriate, feel free to accept it.